# Custom form validation using AngularJS

Tags: jquery, forms, angularjs

I am trying to use AngularJS to validating a form. The form will be spanned across multiple pages and i want to validate each page before the user moves onto the next.

This was pretty straight forward. However, each page can contain multiple tabs and i am not sure how to switch-on and switch-off validation for specific tabs.

As you can see in the fiddle below, '#page1' has 'individual' and 'company'. User can select only one of these 2 and as per that choice, i have to disable the validation on other tab. Adding the 'ng-disabled' attribute dynamically using jQuery is not working.

How can i achieve that? Any help is appreciated.

http://jsbin.com/ijuhos/5/edit

Answer (score 0):

[ngDisabled](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angDisabled) takes an expression. you can set each ngDisabled attribute on each next button to call a function in your controller which checks the active tab, and also does more logic (which you have to figure out, your fiddle is hard to read ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had some progress in the form. I used ng-show to switch between different tabs and ng-disabled to disable the form fields in the hidden tabs. However, the overall form-state is still set to 'invalid' because Angular is validating the disabled form fields. To make things clear, say i have 'Tab-A' and 'Tab-B'. 1. 'Tab-A' is default. 
2. User clicks on a field, angular changes form state to invalid
3. User decides to navigate to 'Tab-B'.
4. Fields in 'Tab-A' are disabled BUT still retain their invalid state.
5. Form retains its invalid state. - ISSUE